# How can I sum in the calculation that I have done in this SQL? i wish to do sum for this two data

Tags: sql

How can I sum in the calculation that I have done in this SQL?

```
select
    ac_invc."fd_st",
    (SUM(net_amount)-(ac_invc."total_amount"-ac_invc."balance_amount")) AS total_amt_due
from "public"."ac_invc" ac_invc 
INNER JOIN "public"."ac_invc_item" ac_invc_item ON ac_invc."id" = ac_invc_item."invoice_id"
where ac_invc."fd_st" = 16
group by ac_invc."fd_st",ac_invc."total_amount",ac_invc."balance_amount"
```

this output became like this:

[image: this output became like this:]

Comment: So what's the issue you are getting ?

Comment: i want to calculate this two output (total_amt_due numeric) data into one. how should i do it?

Comment: So you mean a total sum of 16. Right..

Comment: i want to total sum of total_amt_due..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
     SELECT TB.FD_ST,
           SUM (TB.TOTAL_AMT_DUE)
      FROM (SELECT   AC_INVC."fd_st" AS FD_ST,
                     (  SUM (NET_AMOUNT)
                      - (AC_INVC."total_amount" - AC_INVC."balance_amount") )
                                                                 AS TOTAL_AMT_DUE
                FROM "public"."ac_invc" AC_INVC INNER JOIN "public"."ac_invc_item" AC_INVC_ITEM ON AC_INVC."id" =
                                                                                                       AC_INVC_ITEM."invoice_id"
               WHERE AC_INVC."fd_st" = 16
            GROUP BY AC_INVC."fd_st") TB
      Group by TB.FD_ST
```

Comment: Try now,,I changed it and let me know

Comment: it's still shown two data.. and the first data become -13728.00

Comment: Actually your question is not pretty clear so i need to modify it once agian. Check now.

Comment: @cumi Why did you downvote ? I mean you accepted it and downvoted ?

Comment: @cumi. May be you can again upvote.Seems someone intentionally downvoted without telling reason showing foolishness.

Comment: i'm sorry though, i try to upvote back.. but it's didn't work..thank you though for helping me.